# How to find formating for rosmsg publishing on command line

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, rostopic, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish messages to my robot in order to get it to move in the command line but I can't figure out how to format the rostopic pub /topic /type . I'm having issue with the data and how to find the format for it. I'll include a specific example below.
Command Line Input:

```
$ rosmsg show gazebo_msgs/ModelStates
string[] name
geometry_msgs/Pose[] pose
  geometry_msgs/Point position
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
  geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
    float64 w
geometry_msgs/Twist[] twist
  geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
  geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
```

This is what I'm thinking. Someone please help!

```
rostopic pub -10 /gazebo/model_states gazebo_msgs/ModelStates '"Hello" [] [] [] []"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416588/how-to-find-formating-for-rosmsg-publishing-on-command-line/) by [RichardVZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/147697/richardvz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This terminal command will show you high-level help with various options:

```
$ rostopic pub --help
Usage: rostopic pub /topic type [args...]
...
```

The `[args...]` syntax is a yaml dictionary, which is explained here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/YAMLCommandLine

Also, it's a bad idea to publish to some topics if some node is already publishing. You may seriously confuse the subscribers to that topic.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RichardVZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/147697/richardvz/) on 2023-06-20**:
This page helps a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think more clarification on what you exactly trying to achieve will be great.

But from what I understand if you have a problem with the message format on the terminal, when you use (rostopic pub), you can simply write

rostopic pub -10 /gazebo/model_states gazebo_msgs/ModelStates

Then press TAB button on your keyboard it will autocomplete with the message format required then you can change it with the required values.

---

Originally posted by [Mostafa _1995](https://answers.ros.org/users/154555/mostafa-_1995/) with karma: 11 on 2023-06-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RichardVZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/147697/richardvz/) on 2023-06-20**:
This will work! I didn't know that this was possible thank you.